# Rabbitmq 3.5.6 cannot set AMQP port

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed Rabbitmq (v3.5.6) via brew.

I can use command (*/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server*) to start server, 
and I can use http://localhost:15672/ to browse the management page.

I guess I install Rabbitmq successfully.

I want to change the AMQP port to 5673, and I follow the [document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html), 
edit */usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config* as below, but fail.

```
[
    {rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [5673]}]}
].
```

The port still is 5673. However, I can use this file to set **mqtt** port to 11883 (default 1883).

What happens?

Comment: The file should be here : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

Comment: I found the file should be here: */usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config*, but setting the port doesn't work.

Comment: please ask these kind of questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file should be

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

I thing that your problem is that you are not rebooting your server/computer.

To apply the changes in your configuration file you have to reboot your server.